# How to specify R CMD exec directory?

Tags: r, rserve

Previously I have been able to start Rserve from the command line via:

```
R CMD Rserve
```

After upgrading to 3.0.2 on Ubuntu, I get:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rcmd: 62: exec: Rserve: not found
```

I've tried reinstalling and launching manually via

```
R
> install.packages('rserve')
> ...compiles successfully...
> RServe()
Starting Rserve:
 /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD /home/user1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rserve/libs//Rserve
```

...which works fine.

R CMD Rserve still fails with the same error as above.  I've tried specifying the path via:

```
export RHOME="/home/jwiley/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rserve/libs/"
export R_LIBS="/home/jwiley/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/Rserve/libs/"
```

How can I convince R CMD to use the correct directory?

Comment: To understand your problem better, please try following in your bash (wich command): which  R  and wich Rserve

Comment: Is it possible that your library is not loaded when you start R? Does it work if you add the `library("Rserve")` to your .Rprofile ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case this was the fix (after installing Rserve):

```
cd /usr/lib/R/bin
ln -s /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rserve/libs/Rserve Rserve
```

This fixed the problem on Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS)

R library location may vary, actual path to `Rserve` can be checked from R:

```
system.file("libs", "Rserve", package="Rserve")
```

Answer (score 3):

While starting Rserve as a daemon process from terminal in ubuntu 16.04 I got the same issue.

Commands to fix.

```
apt-cache policy r-cran-rserve
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rserve
```

Answer (score 2):

Commands to fix:

```
cd /usr/lib/R/bin/
ln -sf ../site-library/Rserve/libs/Rserv
ln -sf ../site-library/Rserve/libs/Rserve.db
```