# How to make an upstart service to Rserve?

Tags: r, rserve

I need to start and keep running the `rserve` from `R`.

I have these lines in my `rserve.r` file:

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
```

So, I'm trying to do something like this in my upstart script:

```
description "Rserve service"
author      "Valter Silva"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

respawn

script
    echo $$ > /var/run/rserve.pid
    exec /usr/bin/R /home/valter/R/rserve.R >> /home/valter/test2.log
end script


pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Rserve Starting" >> /var/log/rserve.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/rserve.pid
    echo "[`date`] Rserve Stopping" >> /var/log/rserve.log
end script
```

I know that the service runs because of the output of my file `test2.log`. But it runs only once. What should I do to keep it running ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it runs only once" ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré if I start the R command line and give the commands       `library(Rserve)` and `Rserve()`; Rserve stays in the linux processes list. But if I try to make that in my upstart, nothing happens.

Comment: Try to launch it using `R CMD Rserve` instead ? (see https://rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html#start)

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me the follow error: `/usr/lib/R/bin/Rcmd: 62: exec: Rserve: not found`.

Comment: @ValterHenrique check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370980/how-to-specify-r-cmd-exec-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you (and I) are having so much trouble is that we're asking the wrong question.  The correct question is "**how can we launch Rserve from our client code?**"  Java (and most other) clients have the capability to StartRserve.

The answer to that question is here for the java library: [How to start Rserve automatically from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373372/how-to-start-rserve-automatically-from-java)

or here for the C# library:
https://github.com/SurajGupta/RserveCLI2/blob/master/RServeCLI2.Test/Rservice.cs

---

Another approach would be to learn from [the best](https://github.com/cboettig).  The Rocker project copies [`supervisor.conf`](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/rstudio/supervisord.conf)
to `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`
(see https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/rstudio/Dockerfile#L61)

your `supervisor.conf` could add something like

```
[program:Rserve]
command=/usr/bin/Rserve.sh
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
user=myuser
startsecs=0
autorestart=false
exitcodes=0
```

---

BUT ... 
I did figure it out.  So here's the answer.  I apologize that it's a bit clumsy and distributed.  For me, my biggest obstacle was putting my start/stop scripts in the `/usr/bin` folder (see discussion below)

`/etc/init/Rserve.conf`

```
description "Rserve service"
author "Victor I. Wood"
version "0.01"

# based on
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485131/how-to-make-an-upstart-service-to-rserve

env STARTSCRIPT=/usr/bin/Rserve.sh
env STOPSCRIPT=/usr/bin/Rserve.stop
env LOGFILE=/var/log/Rserve.log


start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

console output

respawn

# tell upstart we're creating a daemon
# upstart manages PID creation for you.
expect fork


pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Rserve Starting" >> $LOGFILE
    echo $$ > /var/run/Rserve.pid
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/Rserve.pid
    echo "[`date`] Rserve Stopping" >> $LOGFILE
    exec $STOPSCRIPT >> $LOGFILE
end script


script
        # My startup script, plain old shell scripting here.
        exec $STARTSCRIPT >> $LOGFILE
#       echo $$ > /var/run/rserve.pid
end script
```

---

`/usr/bin/Rserve.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo --login --set-home --user=myuser bash -c '~/Rserve.sh >~/Rserve.log 2>&1'
```

---

`/usr/bin/Rserve.stop`

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -U myuser Rserve
```

---

`/home/myuser/Rserve.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# launch new Rserve process
R CMD Rserve --RS-conf /home/myuser/Rserve.conf --no-save >~/Rserve.log 2>&1
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/62812/why-isnt-my-upstart-service-starting-on-system-boot?lq=1

I started with the script at 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/62729/how-do-i-set-up-a-service?lq=1
and noted the `initctl` start which might come in handy for debugging.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/62812/why-isnt-my-upstart-service-starting-on-system-boot?lq=1
 noted that the script had to be in `/bin` (but I used `/usr/bin`), and had to be owned by `root`.  Some folks like to use a link to a script elsewhere for the script i `/bin`

as folks here at [How to make an upstart service to Rserve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485131/how-to-make-an-upstart-service-to-rserve)
have suggested, I'm using the Rserve start command that I found in the rServe documentation

```
R CMD Rserve
```

though I've expanded mine to

```
R CMD Rserve --RS-conf /home/myuser/Rserve.conf --no-save >~/Rserve.log 2>&1
```

I'm not exporting the correct pid, so I'm stopping it with a pkill.  A more graceful approach would be

```
RSshutdown(rsc)
```

[How can I shut down Rserve gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225066/how-can-i-shut-down-rserve-gracefully?rq=1)

stdout & stderr confuse upstart, so re-direct all output with `2>&1`
[How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file)

I kinda figured it out by the time I found
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it
and
https://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/
http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/02/14/upstart-scripts-in-ubuntu/
but for folks who just want to get started, those are more practical starting places than the official documentation.

---

### Update

This solution assumes Upstart, which was the original question, but Upstart is no longer the default service manager.  If you'd like to do this on post-16.04 systems, change back to Upstart with

```
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo apt-get purge systemd
```

(from http://notesofaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2016/09/running-upstart-on-ubuntu-1604-lts.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the public documentation of Rserve says, you can start Rserve daemon from a shell script.

Just create a script that executes the following command:

```
echo 'library(Rserve);Rserve(FALSE,args="--no-save --slave --RS-conf <your_own_path>/rserve.conf")'|<R_bin_path>/R --no-save --slave
```

For instance, in my MacOS computer I can start Rserve executing this line:

```
/bin/sh -c "echo 'library(Rserve);Rserve(FALSE,args=\"--slave\")'|/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-save --slave"
```

This command outputs something like this:

```
Starting Rserve:
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --slave 

Rserv started in daemon mode.
```

Make sure to specify "--slave" parameter when you start Rserve.

You can create a shell script (or windows script) and tell the OS to execute this script during the startup process.